# Argular 2 - Open modal/popup from input/textarea to allow for easier entry/viewing

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular2-forms

I need a directive to open a modal or popup when a user focuses in an input or text area. User can potentially enter a lot of text but UI space is limited.

Ideally this would be a directive that can be placed on any control to open the popup, allow user to enter text and when they click on ok, the model property is updated.
An example control to have this is shown below:

```
<textarea id="regime" name="regime" [(ngModel)]="management.regime" class="form-control" maxlength="500"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a modal and dynamically binding the ngModel to the property that has focus. Pretty simple but works once you get correct syntax.